# Superimpose slides on beamer

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I am making a presentation in beamer and  I need to superimpose a diagram in a slide (on top of everything) something like this:
[image: first slide]
[image: diagram superpose]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! With Ti*k*Z that's straightforward.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example}
\foreach \X in {1,...,90} {Example }
\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (current page.south west) 
rectangle (current page.north east) 
node[midway,opacity=0.8,fill=gray!80,scale=pi]
{DIAGRAM};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: PERFECT!  THANKS